# I can't make use of my second class, really unsure how to solve it

Tags: c#, class

When I run it all i am able to do is write the employees name and sales but then it doesn't use the second class and use that information. Can someone help me please? I've been struggling on this for a while!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace consoleapplication9
{
 public class takehomepay
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        const decimal commission = 0.7M; // Commision rate
        const decimal federaltax = 0.18M; // federal tax rate
        const decimal retirement = 0.10M; // retirement rate
        const decimal socialsecurity = 0.06M; // social security rate

        string employeeName;
        decimal commcost = 0; // commision cost
        decimal fedtaxcost = 0; // federal tax cost
        decimal retirecost = 0; // retirement cost
        decimal socseccost = 0; // social security cost
        decimal totalwithholdingcost = 0; // total withholding
        decimal takehomepay = 0; // amount taken home
        decimal totalSales = 0;

        Console.Write("\nEnter employees name: ");
        employeeName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter the total sales amount for the week:");
        totalSales = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

        //Calculations
        commcost = commission * totalSales;
        fedtaxcost = federaltax * commcost;
        retirecost = retirement * commcost;
        socseccost = socialsecurity * commcost;
        totalwithholdingcost = federaltax + retirement + socialsecurity;
        takehomepay = commcost - totalwithholdingcost;
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    private string employeeName;
    private decimal totalSales;
    public Employee()
    {
    }
    public Employee ( string Name)
    {
        employeeName = Name;
    }
    public Employee( string Name, decimal Sales)
    {
        employeeName = Name;
        totalSales = Sales;
    }
    public string EmployeeName
    {
        get
        {
            return employeeName;
        }
        set
        {
            employeeName = value;
        }

    }

    public decimal TotalSales
    {

        get
        {
            return totalSales;
        }

        set
        {
            totalSales = value;
        }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Employee: " + employeeName +
            "\nTotal Sales: " + totalSales;
        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should probably create an instance of your second class somewhere..

Comment: Second Class Details are not mentioned in your code how ever you can create a object of your second class and then access the properties.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the Constructor of your class by newing up an object (Employee)

```
    Console.Write("\nEnter employees name: ");
    employeeName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter the total sales amount for the week:");
    totalSales = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

    //Create an instance of your second class...
    var employee = new Employee(employeeName,totalSales);
    Console.Write(employee);
```

If you need the output from any of your variables you need to write them to the console:

```
    Console.WriteLine(takehomepay);
```

Comment: That worked, however it just gives me  my input of totalSales and doesn't use the maths behind it, also it closes immediately despite console.read();?
I'm getting a warning though on the console.read which is unreachable code detected? I've just been going at this for so long I just have no idea now

Comment: You have a `return` statement before your `Console.Read`.  Nothing after a return gets executed, thus that code is *unreachable*.  Plus, the `Console.Read` statement should be in `Main()` at the end.

Comment: when i delete the return though I get an error
Error (Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement)
Also what do you mean in my Main() at the end? 
Sorry, i've just been doing this one thing for so long now I'm just struggling

Comment: Get rid of `Console.Read();`.  Instead, put it after `Console.Write(employee);`

Comment: Thank you that worked.
Sorry but I just realised I did the question wrong, i needed to give the output of the takehomepay, hence why I the maths wasn't working cause i was using the wrong variable.
    'public override string ToString()
        {
               return "Employee: " + employeeName +
                "\nTake home pay: " + takehomepay;
        }
    }
    }'
I changed the variable to takehomepay however now I'm getting the error takehomepay is a type  but is being used like a variable. Why is it doing this now and how do i solve it? 
Thank you for your help, i'm just majorly stuck

Comment: @nicko'connor if you need the output you'll need to Write it to the console.  See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
employeeName = Console.ReadLine();
```

try

```
Employee employee = new Employee();// this creates an instance of the employee class
employee.EmloyeeName = Console.ReadLine();// this is how you use that instance
```